# Flutter admob banner not showing

Tags: flutter, dart, admob

I set AdMob for my flutter app all is going well but he is not showing, I don t get any errors but the banner is still dark, can someone pls help me with that
[image]

[image]

[image]

I 've watched many tutorials but I can t still fix my problem.

Answer (score 2):

First of all for debugging purposes you should use test id `ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111`, and second I think you should remove `< >` in id

Comment: Thank you, it worked, but how do i know if it s working with my id when i release the app?

Comment: You should add your app to admob first, for admob team to review it, and then you can use your id. Unfortunately you can't view real ads in debug mode

Comment: If your test ads show correctly, there won't be any problem with real ads

Comment: I ve added my app on admob but it work only with test add not with my id app, how long it take to aprove it?